# Download the spacy model fr_core_news_lg

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I use spacy to do some NLP tasks but every time I try to download the **word embbeding** model from spacy

> fr_core_news_lg,

there is:

```
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred
```

This error stops the model download execution.

```
(base) C:\Users\marct>python -m spacy download fr_core_news_lg
Collecting fr_core_news_lg==2.3.0 from https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/fr_core_news_lg-2.3.0/fr_core_news_lg-2.3.0.tar.gz#egg=fr_core_news_lg==2.3.0
  Downloading https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/fr_core_news_lg-2.3.0/fr_core_news_lg-2.3.0.tar.gz (572.0MB)
    85% |███████████████████████████     | 487.3MB 27kB/s eta 0:52:09Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\marct\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 360, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "C:\Users\marct\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 442, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "C:\Users\marct\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 631, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\marct\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 179, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\marct\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 946, in _download_http_url
    _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes, progress_bar)
  File "C:\Users\marct\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 641, in _download_url
    consume(downloaded_chunks)
  File "C:\Users\marct\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 914, in consume
    deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
  File "C:\Users\marct\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 607, in written_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "C:\Users\marct\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\ui.py", line 159, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "C:\Users\marct\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 596, in resp_read
    decode_content=False):
  File "C:\Users\marct\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 494, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "C:\Users\marct\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 459, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "C:\Users\marct\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\marct\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 365, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out.
```

If there is someone who can help me with the problem.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Sounds like a connection speed issue. Have you retried ? The timeout may come from different sources, so it is really hard to say.